# Comparing returned vectors from recursion tree branches

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

Suppose I have a given sum, say sum = 4. I am also given a vector = {2,4}. There are two ways to generate the given sum from the given vector (elements may be reused).
One way is just {4} cause 4 = 4.
Second way is {2,2} cause 2 + 2 = 4.
I have to find the shortest possible combination, therefore in this particular case the answer is {4}.

Here is my approach - I go through the tree, and when on the leaf I get a 0, we hit the base case, return {} vector, and fill up the vector while traversing the tree. When I get to a node, I choose the smaller of the two (or more) vectors. This way when I reach the root node, I should get a vector of the shortest combination that can yield me the target sum.

As of yet, I do not care about time constraints as such, I know there's a lot of repetitive computing going on so I will have to memoize it once I can get the basic version correct.

I have been trying to figure why this code is not working. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<int> findBestSum(int targetSum, const vector<int> &elements, vector<vector<int>> &temp) {
    if (targetSum == 0)
        return {};
    else if (targetSum < 0)
        return {-1};
    else {
        vector<int> small;
        for (auto &i : elements) {
            int remainder = targetSum - i;
            vector<int> returnedVector = findBestSum(remainder, elements, temp);
            if ((!returnedVector.empty() && find(returnedVector.begin(), returnedVector.end(), -1) == returnedVector.end()) || returnedVector.empty()) {
                returnedVector.push_back(i);
                temp.push_back(returnedVector);
            }
            int smallestLength = temp[0].size();
            for (auto &j : temp)
                if (smallestLength >= j.size())
                    small = j;
        }
        return small;
    }
}

int main() {
    int targetSum = 6;
    const vector<int> elements{2, 3, 5}; // answer should be [3,3] however I just get a 3...
    vector<vector<int>> temp;
    vector<int> bestSumVector = findBestSum(targetSum, elements, temp);
    for (auto i : bestSumVector)
        cout << i << " ";
}
```

**Update (14th of July, 2021):**

After a few busy months I have tried to lock horns with this problem and this time my code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

bool howSum(int &targetSum, vector<int> &elementVector, vector<int> &howSumVector, vector<vector<int>> &allSums) {
    static int originaltargetsum = targetSum;
    if (targetSum == 0)
        return true;
    else if (targetSum < 0)
        return false;
    else {
        for (auto i : elementVector) {
            int remainder = targetSum - i;
            bool flag = howSum(remainder, elementVector, howSumVector, allSums);
            if (flag) {
                howSumVector.push_back(i);
                if (targetSum == originaltargetsum ||
                    accumulate(howSumVector.begin(), howSumVector.end(), 0) == originaltargetsum) {
                    allSums.push_back(howSumVector);
                    howSumVector.clear();
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
    int sum = 8; 
    vector<int> elements = {1, 4, 5}; 
    vector<vector<int>> allSums = {};
    vector<int> workingBench = {};
    howSum(sum, elements, workingBench, allSums);
    for (auto &i : allSums) {
        for (auto &j : i) {
            cout << j << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

For this I have `sum` as `8` and `elements` as `{1, 4, 5}`.
Also I'm storing and displaying *all possible solutions* right now (once that is correctly done, finding shortest vector and memoization should be easy). Possible solutions in this case are:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[4, 4]
[5, 1, 1, 1]
[4, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Currently my code only shows the first possible combination. I'm pretty sure I'm returning `true` and `false` incorrectly, please help me out here.

Comment: well i didn't really see anything that pushes something to `small` only the `small = j` modifies it, so that's probably why you only get `3` as your output. Try to debug it.

Comment: `small = j` copies the contents of the smallest `j` (smallest vector from my vector of vectors), that's why I didn't use `push_back(...)` or anything.

Comment: From debugging the code I can see that `j` actually does have the smallest vector that is in `temp`. The problem is with pushing back `i` to `returnedVector` and then pushing the `returnedVector` to `temp`.

Comment: Once one call to `howSum` returns `true`, they will _all_ return true, and you only get one element added to your results array. I think you'll want to add & remove elements from `howSum` as you make the recursive calls, because (with your example) after adding `[4, 1, 1, 1, 1]` you need to keep the `4` in `howSum` while you recurse again trying the next element in `elementVector` (`4`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a stab at this.  I do have a working solution, hopefully it is what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void howSum(int targetSum, const std::vector<int> & elementVector, const std::vector<int> & howSumVector, std::vector<std::vector<int>> & allSums)
{
    static int originaltargetsum = targetSum;

    if (targetSum == 0)
    {
        allSums.push_back(howSumVector);
        return;
    }
    else if (targetSum < 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for (const auto i : elementVector)
        {
            // an element less than or equal to 0 would cause an infinite loop
            if (i <= 0)
                continue;

            std::vector<int> newSumVector = howSumVector;
            newSumVector.push_back(i);

            std::vector<int> newElementVector;
            std::copy_if(std::begin(elementVector), std::end(elementVector), std::back_inserter(newElementVector), [i](int element){ return element >= i; });

            howSum(targetSum - i, newElementVector, newSumVector, allSums);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int sum = 8;
    std::vector<int> elements = { 1, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> allSums = {};
    std::vector<int> workingBench = {};

    howSum(sum, elements, workingBench, allSums);

    for (const auto & i : allSums)
    {
        for (const auto & j : i)
        {
            std::cout << j << " ";
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I think, in general, you were over-thinking or over-engineering the problem.  Like others have mentioned, your current code is returning `true` too early, and nothing besides the first element/combination is tested.  With recursion, it is important to take care in your return cases - really, you only want a base case or two, and otherwise you want to recur.

With the solution I have here, the main thing I have added is copying the current combination of elements for each element you need to test.  That solves your main issue of not testing every combination of numbers.  In addition to that, it seemed better to append to `allSums` when the `targetSum` was reached.  With those changes, I was able to do away with the `bool` return value and simplify the code a bit.  Running the code above gives these solutions:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 4
1 1 1 4 1
1 1 1 5
1 1 4 1 1
1 1 5 1
1 4 1 1 1
1 5 1 1
4 1 1 1 1
4 4
5 1 1 1
```

This does have some duplicates (because of the order things are tested) but I felt like it is good enough since you only want the smallest solution, `4 4`.  To find this, you would just need to sort the `allSums` vector by inner vector size and then take the first entry.

Comment: What would you suggest for memoization in this problem? I'm trying to put the smallest combination for a particular `targetSum` in a `map<int, vector<int>>`. This way we won't have to recompute any overlapping subproblems.

Comment: @DivyanshuVarma if you want to prevent the doing the work of calculating duplicates, I think an elegant way of doing that would be to adjust the `elementVector` inside of the recursive function.  By removing all elements from `elementVector` smaller than `i`, you could guarantee no duplicates.

Comment: you can use a map, but that doesnt make much sense to me - the vector would need to be the key (you wanted to remove duplicates?) and the value of the map would be meaningless.  If you are just using the map to remove duplicate calculations, it seems better to not calculate them in the first place.

Comment: @DivyanshuVarma I have edited my answer with a couple lines added to remove calculation of duplicates.

Comment: Could you please explain the following line?  `std::copy_if(std::begin(elementVector), std::end(elementVector), std::back_inserter(newElementVector), [i](int element){ return element >= i; });`

Comment: @DivyanshuVarma that line is just a condensed way of copying the elements less than `i` into `newElementVector`.  You could use a for loop to do the same thing: `for (const auto j : elementVector) { if (j >= i) newElementVector.push_back(j); }`  A for loop is more common or simpler, but it is 5-6 lines of code vs 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the implementation to correctly process elements of the vector.
In your implementation it doesn't go over all vector items, just the first one.
This is one way to do it if you use vector elements as the first parameter in your function.

```
vector<int> findBestSum(int element, int targetSum, const vector<int>& elements, 
vector<vector<int>>& temp) {
if (targetSum == 0)
    return {};
else if (targetSum < 0)
    return { -1 };
else {
    int remainder = targetSum - element;
    vector<int> returnedVector = findBestSum(element, remainder, elements, temp);
    if ((!returnedVector.empty() && find(returnedVector.begin(), returnedVector.end(), -1) == returnedVector.end()) || returnedVector.empty()) {
        returnedVector.push_back(element);
        return returnedVector;
    }
    return returnedVector;
}
```

}

```
int main() {
  const int targetSum = 6;
  const vector<int> elements{ 2, 3, 5 }; // answer should be [3,3] however I just get a 3...
  vector<vector<int>> temp;
  for (auto i : elements) {
      vector<int> returnedVector = findBestSum(i, targetSum, elements, temp);
      if ((!returnedVector.empty() && find(returnedVector.begin(), returnedVector.end(), -1) == returnedVector.end()) || returnedVector.empty())
          temp.push_back(returnedVector);
  }

  if (temp.size() > 0) {
      vector<int> bestSum = {};
      size_t small = 0;
      size_t smallestLength = temp[0].size();
      for (auto& j : temp)
          if (smallestLength >= j.size()) {
              small = j.size();
              bestSum = j;
          }
      for (auto i : bestSum)
          cout << i << " ";
    }
    else
        cout << " sum not found" << endl;
}
```

Comment: When `findBestSum()` finds a leaf node that is 0, it returns immediately to the top level, but ignores any leaves that might have 0 in between. What I mean is, with `targetSum = 8` and `elements {2 , 3 , 5}` we should get the final answer as {3 , 5}. But this code returns {2 , 2 , 2 , 2}. Just draw a recursion tree and you will get what I'm trying to say.

Comment: It is happening because of `return returnedVector;` inside the `if(...)`. Any suggestions on how to not skip other branches of the tree?

Comment: The implementation I provided is the part of the solution - find the element of vector, which can be used to generate the sum ( 8 in your last example ).  Now you need to find all possible combinations based on vector elements to build the sum. I don't see how your implementation attempts to do it.

Comment: That's what I was having problems with in the first place. How can vectors from all branches be returned to their parent node for comparison? Any ideas?

Comment: In software, it is very important to properly describe the problem you are trying to solve. If you say " there is a vector of integers and a target sum, and I need to find any combination of the integers which would sum to target sum", then I am sure you would get the help with the link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem very quickly. That would help you to approach to the solution you are looking.